# skipSelector not defined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I tried to create a new component in angular and got this error

```
ng g c contact-us
Your global Angular CLI version (8.1.1) is greater than your local
version (7.1.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
skipSelector is not defined
```

Not able to find the answers online. I ran this code inside app folder of my angular project

Comment: Do you have something named skipSelector in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the old angular/cli package in your package.json

To update use:

```
npm r angular-cli
npm i @angular/cli@latest -D
```

run this command on the same level with `package.json`

Comment: removed angular and node, installed again - worked like a charm!. thank you